# Easier way to filter data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, performance, filter

I'm trying to figure out a faster way to filter the tags below instead of using `map` three times.

I've looked a bit at `loadash` and their filter function. But doesn't seem to help speed wise.

```
export function tagFilter(reviews, userTags) {

    const arr = [];

    map(reviews, (review) => {

        let count = 0;

        map(review.tags, (tag) => {
            map(userTags, (userTag) => {
                if (userTag.tag_data.id === tag.id) count += 1;
            });
        });

        arr.push({ review, count });

    });

    arr.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

    const reviewArray = [];

    arr.forEach((reviewObject) => {
        reviewArray.push(reviewObject.review);
    });

    return reviewArray;
}
```

Any suggestions is highly appreciated?

Comment: An example of what contains the variable `reviews` would help us a lot

Answer (score 0):

map, loop, for loop and lodash map from this looping option the fastest is lodash map so i am sure about this you have to use lodash for map no other looping library is faster then lodash

Here are a comparation of the native map against the lodash map
https://jsperf.com/native-map-vs-lodash-map

Aparently lodash is faster